# How do you say "would you" in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, questions

I read many translations of "would you" but I still doubt it. 
I would like to ask someone following question in French  :

> What job would you like to have?

Comment: What many translations have you heard, and why do you "*still doubt it*" (whatever "*it*" is)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to express in your sentence is something you would like, a wish. We're talking about a possibility.

In French, you would translate *would you* with verbs in a conditional tense expressing this idea of the *to like* verb. You can then translate it with *voudriez-vous*, *aimeriez-vous*, ou encore *souhaiteriez-vous*. All of those forms could be used in your sentence :

> Quel travail **voudriez-vous** avoir ?
>
> Quel travail **aimeriez-vous** avoir ?
>
> Quel travail **souhaiteriez-vous** avoir ?

Though, it wouldn't be the same for another sentence. For instance, if your sentence is :

> Would you **do** this ?

You're talking about an action, something you would do. Then, you would translate it with the verb *faire* :

> **Feriez-vous** cela ?

The main thing to keep in mind is that there is no direct word or expression to translate *would you*. You will use a verb in a conditional tense to express this idea of potentiality. Mainly, use the verb after *would you* in your sentence, translate it in French, and conjugate it in a conditional tense :

> Would you **dance** with me ?

Would give :

> **Danseriez-vous** avec moi ?

Comment: "Danseriez-vous avec moi?" is rather formal. You could also ask "Voulez-vous danser avec moi?" or "Est-ce que l'on danse ensemble?" or "Est-ce qu'on danse ensemble?" or even "Un petit pas de danse?".

Answer (score 1):

We usually use the conditional tense

Quel travail **aimeriez-vous** avoir ?

Comment: "Souhaiteriez" too.

Comment: Of course. I believe the important part here is the tense though, the choice of verb remains quite open.

Answer (score 1):

**Would you** is equal to **Voudrais-vous** exactly, because the *you* personal pronoun is *vous* in French.

Comment: Actually, it would be "Voudriez-vous", and not "Voudrais-vous". Please don't answer if your answer gives nothing more than the accepted answer. Here, Isuka have already talked about it...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't anyone use the subjunctive these days? Very polite:

> Veuillez me faire savoir le travail/métier qui vous plait?

Or, simply:

> Qu'est ce que vous voulez faire comme travail/métier?

or, down your route:

> Quel travail vous plairait le plus?

Answer (score -1):

Would you  = Voudrais-tu ? (singular)  Voudriez-vous (more than one person addressing)

Want to dance = Veux-tu danser ?